# Preferred Way to Handle Background Image in MVC View

Tags: image, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 View where I am displaying a table of data. This table is rendered inside a `<div>` tag. What I would like to do is to display a background image that the div contents sit on top of. The image should comprise most, or all, of the div and be somewhat faint and subtle. In other words, it shouldn't stand out. It should almost look like a watermark. I don't have a lot of experience with MVC and HTML/CSS and am not sure how to do this.

I'm not sure what sort of image I should use (PNG, JPG?), or if it even matters and how to make it transparent enough to make it look subtle etc. I'm assuming CSS can handle much of this for me, just not sure where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh it's easy. Give the div a class, eg:

```
 <div class="table-wrapper">
```

At the end of the css file being used on your page, if their is one, write css like this:

```
.table-wrapper{
  background-image: url(/path/to/image);
  /* if the image repeats nicely, tile it, using background-repeat */
  background-repeat: repeat; /* repeat-x, repeat-y and no-repeat are options */
  /* alternatively, you could stretch it to fit the div, using background-size */
  background-size: 100% 100%; 

}
```

You shouldn't see much difference in size between a png or a jpg, as long as you don't use transparency. .pngs with transparency can get make a file big very quickly.

I suggest picking an image that matches the colour of the surrounding area quite closely. This way you can give the impression of a low-contrast or translucent image, without the file-size cost.

Comment: Yes that is pretty easy. Would it help if I set the Opacity in order to give it a more subtle (see through) look (I haven't had a chance to implement your solution yet).